# Can I make my Qt project downloadable through package tool

Tags: qt, apt

I'm wondering if there is a way to make my Qt application be downloadable through for example APT and can be executed?

As an example, I downloaded "pinta" using following command `sudo apt install pinta`
and then i could just write `pinta` in terminal, and it would open the program.

Is it possible to do it Qt projects?

Comment: Related: [https://earthly.dev/blog/creating-and-hosting-your-own-deb-packages-and-apt-repo/](https://earthly.dev/blog/creating-and-hosting-your-own-deb-packages-and-apt-repo/)

Comment: Also: [https://bhavyanshu.me/how-to-make-debian-packages-for-qt-c-based-applications/11/09/2014/](https://bhavyanshu.me/how-to-make-debian-packages-for-qt-c-based-applications/11/09/2014/)

Comment: And: [https://wiki.qt.io/Talk:Deploying_a_Qt5_Application_Linux](https://wiki.qt.io/Talk:Deploying_a_Qt5_Application_Linux)